# (SOLVED) TypeError: spawn is not a function when trying 'npm start' for Expo Router with React Native

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo, expo-router

I am new to React Native and I was trying to test my expo router project but when I used `npm start` I got this error:

> TypeError: spawn is not a function

The error seems to be in the `node_modules/expo/bin/cli.js` file in my project.

I tried reinstalling npm and Nodejs but nothing worked. I am using **Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.**

- npm version : 8.5.1
- Nodejs version : v12.22.9
- expo version : 6.3.2

(Edit)
I think the problem occurred when i installed my expo project. I have created a new project and now it is perfectly working by executing the following command line : `expo-cli start --tunnel`

Comment: How do you try to run the project ?
Guess: Maybe you should use node@16.10.0